# How can I save and display elements within arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, variables, menu

I am trying to create a program where I can store students names and grades and recall and edit them.

So far I have created the user input function for entering the students personal data. This is a coursework questions and I'm not allowed to use dynamic arrays so I've used #define STUDNO 75 and allow the user to set the size of the array with a max of 75.

I have made it as far as creating the menu for the user to input the grade but it is here I'm coming into a problem.

How can I get the program to output the students names instead of the garbled code it displays?

Here are the functions:

```
int studDetails(char name[][25])
{
    int studno; /* Number of students*/
    int x = 0;  /* UI help, showing incremental increase of students*/
    int i, j;

/*Enter the number of students */
printf("Please enter the number of students studying this module:");
printf(" \n\n");
scanf("%2d", &studno);
printf("\n");
getchar();

/*Enter the name of students*/
printf("\n      Please enter the names ");
printf("of the %d students: \n", studno);
for (i =0; i <studno; i++)
{
    printf("\nStudent name %d: ", x, x++);
    scanf("%[^\n]", name[i]);
    getchar();
}
return studno;

/***********************************************************************


int enter(void)
{
    char name[STUDNO][25];
    int subopt =0; /*Access to menu sub-options*/
    int studno; /* Number of students*/
    int x = 0;  /* UI feature, to display number of students*/
    int i, j;       /*Detail for array *//*Student names array */
    int studmark [STUDNO][2]; /*Student marks array */

    printf("\n      Enter Marks\n"); /*Display title*/
    printf("1. Coursework 1\n");
    printf("2. Coursework 2\n");
    printf("3. Coursework 3\n");
    printf("4. Cancel\n\n"); /*Cancel*/

    printf("Please select the option you require: \n");
    scanf("%d", &subopt);
    getchar();
    while (subopt <1, subopt > 4)
    {
        printf("Error. Please enter a valid integer");
        scanf("%d", &subopt);
        getchar();
    }
    switch (subopt)
{
case 1:
    printf("\n      Coursework 1\n");
    printf("Please enter the marks for %s: ", name[i]);
    scanf("%d", &studmark[STUDNO][0]);


case 2:
    printf("\n      Coursework 2\n");
    printf("Please enter the marks for %s: ", name[i]);
    scanf("%d", &studmark[STUDNO][0]);

case 3:
    printf("\n      Coursework 3\n");
    printf("Please enter the marks for %s: ", name[i]);
    scanf("%d", &studmark[STUDNO][0]);
}

return menu();
}
```

Comment: &studmark[STUDNO][0] is a one-past-the-end pointer. That pointer may be formed but not accessed and scanf tries to write to it. Did you forget to iterate over all students? Also your question says 75 but your code says 25 as limit.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the response. I thought the 25 was a character limit within the array and the empty [ ] was to allow user input for the amount of elements in the array. 

What do you mean by iterate over all students?

Comment: Sorry, you are right about the 25 not being STUDNO. It's jsut another fixed sized array that shouldn't be. My name is 34 chars long and all of it plain ascii.

Comment: Okay I can change that to be more inclusive of longer names. Why am I not able to write to the pointer? I don't understand what the issue with the code is here.

Comment: You are using `printf("Please enter the marks for %s: ", name[i]);`. So I would assume you also want to write to `studmark[i]`. But i is never initilized. Did you forget to ask which student to edit? Or make a for loop over all students? YOu are also missing a calls to `studDetail(name);` in enter() or the array of names is uninitialized too.

Comment: `studmark` is an array of size `STUDNO`. So it goes from 0 to STUDNO-1. `studmark[STUDNO]` is past the end of the array.

Comment: I have also pasted the int studDetails(char name[][25]); at the top of the function and now im getting the error message:       "162 51 \\Mac\Home\Documents\Foundation Year\Foundation Programming\Programming Project\V2\SchoolTerminalv2.3.c [Note] each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in"